# Which machine to run cp from for fastest smb performance?

Tags: network-share, file-sharing

I have some huge(multi gb) files I'd like to transfer over a local network. 
There are three computers involved, the source computer A, the destination computer B, and probably a 3rd computer(the computer the person or script doing the copy is on).

Does it make a difference.if I run it on Computer A (from local source to remote smb destination), Computer B (from a remote smb source to local destination), or on C (from a remote smb destination to a remote smb destination)?

Also I'd like to potentially run this for multiple destination machines in parallel, does this change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script on C just executes remote commands on A or B (e.g. via PowerShell or SSH) and the transfer is directly between A and B there is no fundamental difference between the other variants (initiate the transfer either on the source or the target) and all three variants should be more or less equal. But if you try to do something like

```
copy \\serverA\files \\serverB\files
```

on C, you will effectively double the required data transfer, as the data will be copied from A to C and from C to B.

As for the multiple-parallel transfer question: If you mean to copy from A to B and from A to D and A to E in parallel, this doesn't change anything but if the files are the same it might be faster to look for some kind of parallel-copy tool that uses multicasting to send the files only once to the network, as otherwise your network bandwidth will be shared by all transfers, reducing the speed to (1/number of parallel transfers).